# Looking to count a number of times until the number reappear

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to start count in column B until column A sees the #0, and then reset and recount until the next zero, and so forth.

```
   A  B
1  2  1    
2  3  2
3  9  3
4  5  4
5  3  5
6  0  
7  4  1
8  5  2
9  9  3 
10 0  
11 7  1  
.  2  2
.  5  3
.  0
```

--------------------code i have tried and fail--------------------------

```
check = False

For i = 2 To Rows.Count
For j = 1 To 50
        Cells(i, 2).Value = i
     If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(6, 6).Value Then
        check = True
    End If
Next j
 If check = True Then
 j = 1
End If

toAdd = True
Next i
```

Comment: Have you tried any VBA code?  If so, what isn't working?  Is there a reason you don't want to just write an Excel formula?

Comment: i have tried using loop to count to the first zero but i could not figure out how to start the next zero.

Comment: How does cell F6 affect things?  Is that the number `0`?

Comment: Does it have to be vba: Put this in B1 and copy down `=IF(A1=0,"",IF(ROW() = 1,1,IF(INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1)="",1,INDEX(B:B,ROW()-1)+1)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Oooh - I like - I was wondering how to get around the row 1 issue.

Comment: yes i enter the #0 into the cell

Comment: @ScottCraner Formula is good too. GREAT!! thank you.

Comment: Scott's formula is infinitely better than any VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will do what you say you wanted to do in the question:

```
Dim r As Long
For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(r, "A").Value = 0 Then 
        Cells(r, "B").Value = ""
    ElseIf r = 1 Then
        Cells(r, "B").Value = 1
    ElseIf Cells(r - 1, "A").Value = 0 Then
        Cells(r, "B").Value = 1
    Else
        Cells(r, "B").Value = Cells(r - 1, "B").Value + 1
    End If
Next
```

---

This could also be done using an Excel formula of

```
=IF(A2=0,"",IF(A1=0,1,B1+1))
```

in cell B2 and copying it down.  But that relies on the data starting in row 2 (or later), because the references to A1 and B1 (i.e. the previous row) would crash if your data started in row 1.

Comment: yes they both work great! wow so many different method, ill try to digest this. thank you!

Comment: i am look at this line of code and could not figure out. Is this mainly for Row 1 issue?                                                                                                             [ElseIf r = 1 Then
        Cells(r, "B").Value = 1]

Comment: @FrankLe - yes, that is just to handle row 1 - because subsequent tests look at row `r - 1` which wouldn't work if `r` was 1 (Excel doesn't have a row 0)